# Write down the inverse of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Write down the inverse of the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know only how to find the inverse of matrix only in $3\times 3$ matrix but I don't know how to find the inverse of matrix in $5\times 5$ matrix.
If anybody help me I would be more thankful...

Comment: **Hint:** write the augmented matrix $[A | I]$ and perform Gaussian Elimination by reducing to $[I | A^{-1}]$. You should find $$A^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: See here for mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/133781

Comment: thanks @moo,,,but   how u got  -2,-3  im not getting

Comment: Show the RREF steps so we can spot the issue. It can be solved with two row calculations!

Comment: ok let me try @ moo

Comment: i got it,,,,, thank a ...lots  @ Moo

Comment: If you know how to find the inverse of a $3\times3$ matrix, then you can do this one, too. In block form, this matrix is $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I_2&0\\ \hline 0&B\end{array}\right]$, which has inverse $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I_2&0\\ \hline 0&B^{-1}\end{array}\right]$. Here, the $3\times3$ inverse is quite easy to compute, too.

Comment: @amd Does this method need a proof? Can we always separate matrix like this to derive the inverse?

Comment: @Ying You can always decompose a matrix into blocks and treat those blocks as elements of a smaller matrix, but it’s not always useful to do so. In this case, the matrix is *block-diagonal*, which makes computing the inverse easier.